# create index, where advantage has null equality columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following index statistics obtained through a DML query.
The query has been identified by SQL server as needing some work.

```
Equality: NULL  
Inequality: [Date], [TransactionType]
Include: [TenantId], [InvestmentId]
```

The equality being `null` throws me a little, it could be correct though, as I am selecting pages of data based on a date.

Will creating an index on the inequality columns help?

Comment: What does the plan say?

Comment: How do I get the plan from the missing index table? I am querying dm_db_missing_index_details

Comment: Yes, creating an index on the inequality columns will help. The rule of thumb is equality columns before inequality columns in the key.

Comment: thanks, it's very strange there are no equality columns, since almost every query in the system has to join the tenantId, I will need to investigate further, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @sean, do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, creating an index on the inequality columns will help. The rule of thumb is equality columns before inequality columns in the key.